# Javascript/CSS Sidebar Toggle

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a sidebar toggle which would change a couple of things in the CSS but I can't quite get it to work.

I have a DIV which is currently changing it's input on hover from SITENAME.COM to MENU. I want the div #site-name to toggle the sidebar on the left.

The DIV #site-name is inside a container/wrapper DIV called #body.

It toggles correctly, but it will not reset the body margin back to 0. After opening the sidebar, the wrapper div keeps the margin set by the open function.

I haven't coded for a while so any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="site-name" onclick='openNav();'>MAN&WOLF.MEDIA</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function()
      {
          var cart_visible = false;

          $('#site-name').on('click', function()
          {
              if ( cart_visible )
                  $('#mySidebar').css('margin-left', '-250px');

              else
                  $('#mySidebar').css('margin-left', '0px');
                  $('#body').css('margin-left', '0px');



              cart_visible = !cart_visible;
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you didn't wrap your else block in brackets.  So the line: `$('#body').css('margin-left', '0px');` is called whether you're opening or closing the menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cart_visible = false;

  $('#site-name').on('click', function() {
    if (cart_visible) {
      $('#mySidebar').css('width', '0');
      $('#body').css('margin-left', '0');
    } else {
      $('#mySidebar').css('width', '250px');
      $('#body').css('margin-left', '250px');
    }
    cart_visible = !cart_visible;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
}

#mySidebar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: coral;
  margin-left: -250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div id="site-name">MAN&WOLF.MEDIA</div>
  <div id="mySidebar">
    Sidebar content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know the toggle works, but it doesn't change the state of the #body margin like I want it to. I have uploaded it so you can see a live version: https://deklol.github.io/notepadsite/

When the Sidebar opens I want it to give #body a left-margin of 250px, and when it closes the body left-margin goes back to 0.

Comment: @dekl0l Oh sorry.  That's right.  You mentioned that in your original question. I've updated my answer to more closely mimic your page.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the margin-left attribute to #body when opening up the side bar.

```
if ( cart_visible ) {
    $('#mySidebar').css('margin-left', '-250px');
    $('#body').css('margin-left', '0px');
} else {
    $('#mySidebar').css('margin-left', '0px');
    $('#body').css('margin-left', '250px');
}
```